# Vuex - rawModule is undefined moving from single to multiple modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Moved my project from single module in vuex store to multiple following the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html).

It states that the specific module should be accessed like so:

```
store.state.a // -> `moduleA`'s state
```

This is when accessing the state of a module.  It fails to say how to access getters and mutations as well as the commands like 'commit' and 'replaceState' for a specific module so I made my own conclusion:

```
store.getters.a
store.mutations.a
store.a.commit()
store.a.replaceState()
```

1) Are those conclusions correct?

2) Using these I get a really general error message:

```
TypeError: rawModule is undefined
```

Here is my store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    listingModule: listingModule,
    openListingsOnDashModule: listingsOnDashModule,
    closedListingsOnDashModule: listingsOnDashModule
  }
})

const listingsOnDashModule = {...}
const listingModule = {...}
// their content hasn't changes since the single module approach.
```

Answer (score 6):

This error:

```
TypeError: rawModule is undefined
```

is caused by trying to register `undefined` as a module, you are probably importing `undefined` by accident when registering the module.

As for the syntax `store.state.a` is correct. With the rest the `.a` should just be omitted unless you are explicitly defining a namespace.